# Firebase JsonMappingException

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have JsonMappingException when I try to reach the arraylist as you can see in below. I tried to get it with List popular_attributes but it makes error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: json field]

[image: this is the exception]

```
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MyModel model = new MyModel();
                Hotel hotel = postSnapshot.getValue(Hotel.class);
                model.setHotelName(hotel.getName());
                model.setHotelImage(hotel.getMain_image());
                model.setHotelAdress(hotel.getAdressBooking());

                if (hotel.getPopular_attributes() != null) {
                    model.setHotelProperty(hotel.getPopular_attributes());
                }
            }        
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you display your parsing method?

Comment: I added my parsing method

Comment: @CanerGulgec Please have a look at how to construct a [minimal, *complete* verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, we have no way of knowing what location `ref` points to, nor what the `Hotel` and `MyModel` class look like. But adding them will likely make your question a lot longer. Instead: read the link I provided on how to provide an MCVE, since it's the best way to get help for problems such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `implement Serializable` to your model class and try to use `Map` in stead of `List`.

Hope it helps.